# std::bit_cast to pointer type not useable in constexpr context

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr, bit-cast

Reading thru https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1517 I got the idea to get rid of the non-constexpr `reinterpret_cast` from my µC code (e.g. `C` could be a µC internal peripheral on address `0x100`). Therefore I tried `std::bit_cast`-ing to a pointer type.

```
struct C {
    inline static constexpr uintptr_t address = 0x100;
    inline static constexpr C* ptr1 = std::bit_cast<C*>(address);
    inline static /*constexpr*/ C* ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<C*>(address);
};
```

But according to the standard this is not possible because in this case `std::bit_cast` is not allowed to be constexpr (like `reinterpret_cast`).

Looks like this is still not possible? But why?

Comment: These are the answers you might seek:  
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast#Notes
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing

Mainly due to the possibility of Undefined Behavior.
It is marked ``constexpr`` but the implementation wouldn't able to evaluate it to a constant.

Comment: `std::bit_cast` with pointer types is exactly the same as `reinterpret_cast`, so the rules for why that isn't allowed in a constant expression are the same reasons why you can't use `bit_cast`.